# Gmail Push Notifications not stopping after revoking app access

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-oauth

I'm using the Gmail Push API to `watch()` a user's inbox and receive updates in a PubSub topic (which has a webhook subscription to my app).

If the user disconnect its Gmail inbox within my app, I can call `stop()` and the notifications are no longer received by my application.

However, if the user disconnect its Gmail account by revoking access in the security settings of his Google account, my application continue to receive notifications for his Gmail account, and I can't find how to stop them... because calling stop() won't work anymore with the revoked token.

Big thanks to anyone who can help :)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Able to find the solution?

Comment: @Sk.Irfan Nope, I submitted a bug report on their tracker: issuetracker.google.com/issues/70961654